# in CoffeeScript, how can I use a variable as a key in a hash?

Tags: coffeescript, hashmap, literals

eg:

[image: wtf]

So:

```
foo = "asdf"
{foo: "bar"}
eval foo

# how do I get {"asdf": "bar"} ?

# this will throw parse error:
{(eval foo): "bar"}
```

This is a simple syntax question: how do I get CoffeeScript to construct a hash dynamically, rather than doing it by hand?

Comment: To be clear, `{(eval(foo)): "bar"}` is invalid JavaScript; the object literal syntax only allows literal strings as keys. To support dynamic keys, CoffeeScript would have to convert that code to something like `__obj = {}; __obj[eval(foo)] = "bar";`.

Answer (score 47):

For anyone that finds this question in the future, as of CoffeeScript 1.9.1 interpolated object literal keys are supported!

The syntax looks like this:

```
myObject =
  a: 1
  "#{ 1 + 2 }": 3
```

See https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/commit/76c076db555c9ac7c325c3b285cd74644a9bf0d2

Comment: That's the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @KonstantinSchubert Yes, it's a special case of string interpolation. See http://coffeescript.org/#strings

Comment: @bcherny Ah, thanks! I wasn't aware that string interpolation requires double quotes.

Comment: I dont think you even need the quotes. `[ 1 + 2 ]: 3` will also work.

Answer (score 40):

Why are you using `eval` at all? You can do it exactly the same way you'd do it in JavaScript:

```
foo    = 'asdf'
h      = { }
h[foo] = 'bar'
```

That translates to this JavaScript:

```
var foo, h;
foo = 'asdf';
h = {};
h[foo] = 'bar';
```

And the result is that `h` looks like `{'asdf': 'bar'}`.

Comment: +1.  I have actually found myself extending my prototypes to include a generic function like `getByKey` that does this for me when I need to do it often.

Answer (score 11):

CoffeeScript, like JavaScript, does not let you use expressions/variables as keys in object literals. This was support briefly, but was removed in version 0.9.6. You need to set the property after creating the object.

```py
foo = 'asdf'

x = {}
x[foo] = 'bar'
alert x.asdf # Displays 'bar'
```

Answer (score 9):

Somewhat ugly but a one-liner nonetheless (sorry for being late):

`{ "#{foo}": bar }`

Comment: Depending on your coffeescript version, this might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use Coffeescript's minimal syntax for defining your associative array, I suggest creating a simple two line method to convert the `variable name` keys into the variable values after you've defined the array.

Here's how I do it (real array is much larger):

```
@sampleEvents = 
   session_started:
          K_TYPE: 'session_started'
          K_ACTIVITY_ID: 'activity'

   session_ended:
          K_TYPE: 'session_ended'

   question_answered:
          K_TYPE: 'question_answered'
          K_QUESTION: '1 + 3 = '
          K_STUDENT_A: '3'
          K_CORRECT_A: '4' #optional
          K_CORRECTNESS: 1 #optional
          K_SECONDS: 10 #optional
          K_DIFFICULTY: 4 #optional


for k, event of @sampleEvents
    for key, value of event
        delete event[key]
        event[eval(key.toString())] = value
```

The `SampleEvents` array is now:

```
{ session_started: 
   { t: 'session_started',
     aid: 'activity',
     time: 1347777946.554,
     sid: 1 },
  session_ended: 
   { t: 'session_ended', 
     time: 1347777946.554, 
     sid: 1 },
  question_answered: 
   { t: 'question_answered',
     q: '1 + 3 = ',
     sa: '3',
     ca: '4',
     c: 1,
     sec: 10,
     d: 4,
     time: 1347777946.554,
     sid: 1 },
```

Comment: Why do you need `eval` in the last line?

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
foo = "asdf"

eval "var x = {#{foo}: 'bar'}"
alert(x.asdf)
```

Comment: this is pretty clever, but a bad idea from a security/perf/best practice point of view