# Using a variable as a hash key in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

Let's say I have this hash in Coffeescript:

```
exercises =
  stretchedPrayer:
    name: "Stretched Prayer"
    sound: "28-stretched-prayer"
  bandStretch:
    name: "Band Stretch"
    sound: "13-band-stretch"
```

I can correctly get the name of the first exercise with the following code:

```
exercises.stretchedPrayer.name
```

What I want to do is call the same name but I will know which exercise I want from a variable extracted from an id on the web page.

In other words, if I have a variable such as

```
myExercise = "stretchedPrayer"
```

How can I get the name of the practice in the hash just using this variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [in CoffeeScript, how can I use a variable as a key in a hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699479/in-coffeescript-how-can-i-use-a-variable-as-a-key-in-a-hash)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use square brackets, like you would do in JavaScript.

```
exercises[myExercise].name
```

`object[property]` is the same as `object.<<property's value>>`

Comment: Thanks a lot Dogbert. It did it :-)